# Unexpected end of JSON input (throw err; ^)

Tags: javascript, json

```
const fs = require("fs");
  

const users = require("./users");
   
let user = {
    name: "New User",
    age: 30,
    language: "Russian"
};
   
users.push(user);
   
fs.writeFile("users.json", JSON.stringify(users), err => {
     
    if (err) throw err; 
   
    console.log("Done writing");
});
```

если убрать throw err; ошибка повториться

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1109

```
throw err;
^
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

```
at parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Так ошибку вам даёт `require('./users')`, при чём тут запись?

Comment: Да, это не ваше `if (err) throw err; ` в скрипте — адрес файла в сообщении об ошибке ссылается на загрузчик модулей, так что ошибка где-то в вашем файле модуля.